# Using ffmpeg to generate multiple resolutions with the exact same keyframe positions

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, flv

There are a bunch of resources on how to use ffmpeg to convert X to Y and so forth but I can't seem to be able to generate different resolutions of the same file with the same keyframe and frame positions.

The keyframe positions are important because they allow the player to jump from one bitrate to another.

These videos are intended for Flash.

I keep on getting results like this from the validation tool.

```
failed on frame 1670
[FrameInfo 1670, type 9, timecode 23565, seekable 1670]
[FrameInfo 1670, type 9, timecode 23565, seekable 1525]
```

Even worse, sometimes it takes to re-ordering the frames

```
failed on frame 1
[FrameInfo 1, type 9, timecode 0, seekable 1]
[FrameInfo 1, type 8, timecode 0, seekable -1]
```

When trying to validate the sample videos that are installed with Adobe Flash Media Server they are ok

```
Comparing files
0: G:\VOD\sample1_150kbps.flv
1: G:\VOD\sample1_500kbps.flv
2: G:\VOD\sample1_700kbps.flv
3: G:\VOD\sample1_1500kbps.flv
Index, Keyframes, and Timecodes are Validated across all files
```

Sample `ffmpeg` command I run at different resolutions.  Adobe Media Encoder is also producing video with different keyframe positions so I don't know whats going on here.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf scale=1270:720 -c:a copy output.flv
```

**ffmpeg 720p**

```
ffmpeg -i .\big_buck_bunny_1080p_surround.avi -vf scale=1280:720 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -ac 2  big_buck_bunny_720.flv
```

**ffmpeg 480p**

```
ffmpeg -i .\big_buck_bunny_1080p_surround.avi -vf scale=854:480 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -ac 2  big_buck_bunny_480.flv
```

**ffmpeg console output**

```
ffmpeg version N-59433-g4aa9c91 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 29 2013 22:01:53 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopenco
re-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-li
bvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 59.100 / 52. 59.100
  libavcodec     55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  0.103 /  4.  0.103
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from '.\big_buck_bunny_1080p_surround.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : AVI-Mux GUI 1.17.7, Aug  8 2006  20:59:17
    JUNK            :
  Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12455 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 tbr, 24 tb
n, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
File 'big_buck_bunny_720.flv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Y
[libx264 @ 029deec0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 029deec0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 029deec0] profile Main, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 029deec0] 264 - core 140 r2377 1ca7bb9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.or
g/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_thr
eads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 r
c=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'big_buck_bunny_720.flv':
  Metadata:
    JUNK            :
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 2
4 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=14315 fps= 73 q=-1.0 Lsize=  120952kB time=00:09:56.49 bitrate=1661.1kbits/s
video:110887kB audio:9321kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.619082%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] frame I:151   Avg QP:17.09  size:115286
[libx264 @ 029deec0] frame P:5374  Avg QP:21.41  size: 14154
[libx264 @ 029deec0] frame B:8790  Avg QP:25.91  size:  2284
[libx264 @ 029deec0] consecutive B-frames: 11.5% 15.5% 13.3% 59.7%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] mb I  I16..4: 24.0%  0.0% 76.0%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] mb P  I16..4:  4.0%  0.0%  3.5%  P16..4: 29.3% 11.1%  7.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:45.1%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.4%  B16..8: 22.4%  1.7%  0.4%  direct: 0.8%  skip:74.1%  L0:37.5% L1:5
8.0% BI: 4.5%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 51.5% 64.4% 37.6% inter: 7.3% 10.1% 1.3%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 40% 23%  9% 28%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 18% 15%  7%  8% 10%  7%  7%  6%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 21% 17% 10%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.9% UV:3.6%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] ref P L0: 62.4% 16.9% 15.2%  5.3%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] ref B L0: 89.3%  9.1%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] ref B L1: 94.3%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 029deec0] kb/s:1522.96
```

**Validation Results**

```
Comparing files
0: G:\VOD\big_buck_bunny_480.flv
1: G:\VOD\big_buck_bunny_720.flv
>> Comparison failed on frame 13181
0: [FrameInfo 13181, type 9, timecode 185958, seekable 12794]
1: [FrameInfo 13181, type 9, timecode 185958, seekable 13181]
```

Comment: How can we make recommendations without seeing your `ffmpeg` commands and the complete `ffmpeg` console output?

Comment: edited - I also tried setting `-g 90` to see if that would fix the keyframe interval and it didn't.

Comment: The console output is missing.

Comment: In the middle of testing a batch from Adobe Media Encoder - computer is useless for another 2 1/2 hours.  They are only 15 minute pieces.  I was trying to avoid long encodes but it seems to want to take this long.

Comment: The `-t` option in `ffmpeg` can be used to limit the output duration.

Comment: I added the ffmpeg output as requested

Answer (score 3):

First get a newer version of ffmpeg, there are regular changes in particular in the newer releases you can force keyframes using an algorithm e.g.

```
 -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)'
```

This would force a keyframe every 2 seconds, which is very frequent and would only be used if say you were fragmenting your video into 2 second fragments, for example with use in a MPEG-DASH profile.

In addition here is a small script I wrote that can check keyframe alignment on the generate video is what is expected.
https://gist.github.com/sinkers/4d02b0c57843dbc6d191

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer is to use 2 pass encoding. On pass one, ffmpeg creates the logfile and keyframe information in two files. I just pass the output to /dev/null. Then run pass 2 multiple times with different bitrates. The resulting video files should have keyframe alignment.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -pass 1 -movflags +faststart -aspect 1280:720 -s 1280x720 -profile:v "high" -level "4.0" -c:v libx264 -b:v 5000k -threads 0 -f rawvideo -an -y /dev/null && \

ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -pass 2 -movflags +faststart -aspect 1280:720 -s 1280x720 -profile:v "high" -level "4.0" -c:v libx264 -b:v 5000k -threads 0 -y output_5000_720p.mp4

ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -pass 2 -movflags +faststart -aspect 1280:720 -s 1280x720 -profile:v "high" -level "4.0" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -threads 0 -y output_2500_720p.mp4
```

For windows based ffmpeg use NUL instead of /dev/null.

This method keeps the encoders ability to adjust I-frame placement to adjust for sudden scene differences rather than "hand cuffing" it to a set GOP size and keyframe interval.

Comment: I'll try to test this soon.  The dynamic GOP size is always preferred to conserve bandwidth on playback so this would be a much better solution.

Comment: Yes it is preferred....however, just note that it's best to use the highest bitrate you will be using for the first pass. There is a loss in compression efficiency on the lower bandwidth versions but will provide the best overall quality.